# Regular graphs of tangent spheres

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

**Problem 1.** Let several non-overlapping spheres in $\mathbb{R^3}$ are given. For which $n$ it is possible that each sphere is tangent to exactly $n$ other spheres?

Consider the smallest sphere. Since the kissing number of $\mathbb{R^3}$ is 12, then $n \le 12$. Using stereographic projection of $120$-cell we obtain example of $120$ spheres with $n=12$. If you delete some spheres from this configuration, it is possible to construct examples for each $n$ except for $n=11$ (See [Deleting vertices of a regular graph to obtain a regular graph](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425366/deleting-vertices-of-a-regular-graph-to-obtain-a-regular-graph?noredirect=1#comment1094002_425366) , comment of @RobPratt). Does an example exist for $n=11$?

**Problem 2.** Let several non-overlapping unit spheres in $\mathbb{R^3}$ are given. For which $n$ it is possible that each sphere is tangent to exactly $n$ other spheres?

Considering lowest sphere we obtain $n\le 8$.
Using regular polyhedra it is easy to construct examples for $n\le 5$. Is it possible to construct examples for $n=6,7,8$?

**Remark.** It is also interesting to consider these problems in greater dimensions. Here [Chromatic number of graphs of tangent closed balls](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8232/chromatic-number-of-graphs-of-tangent-closed-balls?rq=1) there is a discussion on chromatic number of arbitrary graphs of tangent spheres.

Comment: If we consider the standard hexagonal closed packing, which is known to be the most efficient way to pack spheres of radius $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$, we have a sphere that is tangent to $12$ other spheres.
Now, since we can remove them one by one having any solution between $0$ and $12$ itself, is it possible to use this property in order to simplify some of the problems by checking the arrangements of those different "solid" sets of $1, 2, 3, \dots, 13$ spheres?

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. We have a finite number of spheres.

Comment: I was focusing myself on some general bound holding for any $n : n \geq c$, for some $c \in \mathbb{N}$. My argument is quite unuseful if $n$ is not a "large" value, I know. Maybe, we should start to check whether or not a solution to Problem 2 exists for $n=6$.